# How does encrypting JWT's payload improve security

Tags: security, https, jwt, jwe

[On this website](https://jwt.io/introduction), it says:

> Do note that for signed tokens this information, though protected
> against tampering, is readable by anyone. Do not put secret
> information in the payload or header elements of a JWT unless it is
> encrypted.

This part is clear to me, even by using the built-in https://jwt.io/ debugger I can see that the header and payload are only base64-encoded.

However, I do not understand how encrypting here (JWE is the term?) can improve security?

In the examples I saw the user passes their credentials [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYYMk.png) and then [uses the token](https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2022/08/secure-minimal-api-03-100931044-orig.jpg?auto=webp&quality=85,70) they received (I understand the example is flawed as it does not use HTTPS - I'm asking specifically about HTTPS requests here).

So my question is if sending user credentials via HTTPS POST's request body is OK and best practice why wouldn't the same be true for the JWT's header or payload?

Comment: Sending unhashed user passwords over HTTPS isn't best practice. It's common, but it's bad. Passwords should be stretched before sending to the server. But that's not really the point here. You *are* encrypting the JWT. That's what HTTPS does. You're probably thinking that "send to a web server" is the only way JWTs are used so HTTPS is assumed. That's not close to true. They also can be stored on disk, or sent over a wide variety of protocols, including unencrypted protocols (such as your example of HTTP without TLS).

Comment: @RobNapier - oh yeah, like, for example, when I want to store the token in the database. And indeed, I was only thinking about "send to a web server" scenario but there's surely other scenarios where tokens can be used - makes total sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary notes :

Each time something must be kept secret, you need to ask yourself who can share this secret to understand why it should be kept secret and therefore how to keep it secret.

Here, we have two objects that need to be kept secret, the token and its payload:

- The token must be shared by the client and the service: it lets the client prove to the server that the client has an authorization to do a request, since the information is only known by those two parties;
- The payload of the token does not need to be shared with the client, the information in the payload (identity about the client and claims about its rights to do something) is only here for the server to read it and take decisions from it.

therefore, sending the token inside an HTTPS flow lets the token only be known by the client and the server, not anybody else.

And encrypting the content of the token lets the information in this token only being known by the server.

This way, information is only disclosed to parties that need to know about it. This is a basic rule of information security.

> However, I do not understand how encrypting here (JWE is the term?) can improve security?

As noted previously, this improves security because the payload has not to be disclosed to the client.

> my question is if sending user credentials via HTTPS POST's request body is OK and best practice why wouldn't the same be true for the JWT's header or payload?

As noted previously, this is because when dealing with information security, you should never share information that is not needed to be shared. Since the credentials send by the client need to be disclosed to the server, because this is the only practice with such a credentials type that can let the server check that the client owns the good credentials, and since it is sent over a secured channel, no one else can get those secrets, therefore this practice is a best practice. But disclosing the content of the token (payload and signature) to the client is not needed to perform the authentication. So it would not be a good practice to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may be helpful

```
import jwt
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import hashlib


# Get the current timestamp in seconds
def get_current_unix_timestamp():
    return str(int(datetime.now().timestamp()))


# Convert the current Unix timestamp to a human-readable format
def get_human_readable_timestamp(timestamp):
    current_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
    return current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


# Encode the user ID with the timestamp using XOR operation
def encode_userid_with_timestamp(userid, current_unix_timestamp, secret_key):
    # Hash the timestamp and trim to 32 characters
    hashed_timestamp = hashlib.sha256((current_unix_timestamp + secret_key.decode()).encode()).hexdigest()[:32]

    # Combine the hashed timestamp with the user ID
    data = userid + "|" + hashed_timestamp
    data_bytes = data.encode()

    # Perform XOR operation
    repeated_key = secret_key * ((len(data_bytes) // len(secret_key)) + 1)
    repeated_key = repeated_key[:len(data_bytes)]
    encoded_data_bytes = bytes([a ^ b for a, b in zip(data_bytes, repeated_key)])

    # Encode the result in Base64 and return
    encoded_data = base64.b64encode(encoded_data_bytes).decode()
    return encoded_data


# Decode the XOR-encoded data
def decode_userid_timestamp(encoded_data, key):
    # Decode from Base64
    encoded_data_bytes = base64.b64decode(encoded_data.encode())

    # Perform XOR operation
    repeated_key = key * ((len(encoded_data_bytes) // len(key)) + 1)
    repeated_key = repeated_key[:len(encoded_data_bytes)]
    decoded_data_bytes = bytes([a ^ b for a, b in zip(encoded_data_bytes, repeated_key)])

    # Separate the user ID and the hashed timestamp
    decoded_data = decoded_data_bytes.decode()
    userid, hashed_timestamp = decoded_data.split("|")

    # Return the hashed timestamp
    return userid, hashed_timestamp


def main():
    userid = "23243232"
    xor_secret_key = b'generally_user_salt_or_hash_or_random_uuid_this_value_must_be_in_dbms'
    jwt_secret_key = 'yes_your_service_jwt_secret_key'

    current_unix_timesstamp = get_current_unix_timestamp()
    human_readable_timestamp = get_human_readable_timestamp(current_unix_timesstamp)

    encoded_userid_timestamp = encode_userid_with_timestamp(userid, current_unix_timesstamp, xor_secret_key)
    decoded_userid, hashed_timestamp = decode_userid_timestamp(encoded_userid_timestamp, xor_secret_key)

    jwt_token = jwt.encode({'timestamp': human_readable_timestamp, 'userid': encoded_userid_timestamp}, jwt_secret_key, algorithm='HS256')
    decoded_token = jwt.decode(jwt_token, jwt_secret_key, algorithms=['HS256'])

    print("")
    print("- Current Unix Timestamp:", current_unix_timesstamp)
    print("- Current Unix Timestamp to Human Readable:", human_readable_timestamp)
    print("")
    print("- userid:", userid)
    print("- XOR Symmetric key:", xor_secret_key)
    print("- JWT Secret key:", jwt_secret_key)
    print("")
    print("- Encoded UserID and Timestamp:", encoded_userid_timestamp)
    print("- Decoded UserID and Hashed Timestamp:", decoded_userid + "|" + hashed_timestamp)
    print("")
    print("- JWT Token:", jwt_token)
    print("- Decoded JWT:", decoded_token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

https://github.com/password123456/some-tweak-to-hide-jwt-payload-values

Comment: Thank you kindly, but @RobNapier already answered my question.